# Calculate area in square meters from degrees?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, python-2.7

I have a polygon shapefile in geographic coordinate system, I would like to calculate area in square meters in QGIS using Python.

Is there any formula or equation to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a Python script or just the formula to calculate the area for each polygon? There's a `$area` formula used in the **Field Calculator** but I am unsure how to incorporate that into Python.

Comment: Questions about measuring lengths/areas with data in geographic coordinates are very common nowadays. What you need to do is to project your data into a suitable projected coordinate system that is using meters as units. What is the suitable CRS is something that has been dealt with in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/1km-circles-around-lat-long-points-in-many-places-in-world

Comment: I required the formula to calculate the area from GCS...

Comment: I found an answer to your question.

Comment: I followed steps in Answer above, and I dont have the same result. I have problems with QgsDistanceArea, area is not calculated, or is calculated in degrees. wb=iface.activeLayer() feat = wb.selectedFeatures() area = QgsDistanceArea() #creating object area.setEllipsoid('WGS84') #setting ellipsoid True area.setEllipsoidalMode(True) #setting ellipsoidal mode geom = feat[0].geometry().asPolygon() print "Continental Spain area is %.2f km2" % (area.measurePolygon(geom[0])/1e6) Result is: Continental Spain area is 0.00 km2 I use Qgis Wien 2.8.2

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with the class **QgsDistanceArea** of PyQGIS. For testing this, I am going to use the [world_borders.shp](https://db.tt/9LWKpOjm) shapefile and selecting the continental area of Spain (select feature); as in the below image:

[image]

After, I ran this code in the Python Console of QGIS:

```
wb=iface.activeLayer()

feat = wb.selectedFeatures()

geom = feat[0].geometry().asPolygon()

print len(geom[0])  #length of geom (1143 in total)

print geom[0][0:9] #Slice of 9 first QgsPoint (1143 in total)
                   #of polygon geometry (geographic coordinates)

print geom[0][-1] #checking that the last point is the same as
                  #the first one

area = QgsDistanceArea() #creating object

area.setEllipsoid('WGS84')  #setting ellipsoid

area.setEllipsoidalMode(True) #setting ellipsoidal mode

#calculating area
print "Continental Spain area is %.2f km2" % (area.measurePolygon(geom[0])/1e6)
```

Results were:

```
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
execfile(u'/home/zeito/scriptspyqgis/area_geografic.py'.encode('UTF-8'))
1143  #vertex number for Continental Spain Polygon
[(-0.761016,37.846), (-0.801389,37.8014), (-0.841944,37.7489), (-0.858333,37.7217), 
(-0.86,37.7167), (-0.8575,37.7119), (-0.814167,37.6647), (-0.804722,37.6572), 
(-0.786945,37.6478)]  #Slice of 9 first QgsPoint (1143 in total)
(-0.761016,37.846) #last point
Continental Spain area is 494564.85 km2
```

Wikipedia reports a total area of 504,782 km2 (including insular territories).

**Note editing:**

This code takes into account the possibility of Multi parts or Single parts.

```
area = QgsDistanceArea() #creating object

area.setEllipsoid('WGS84')  #setting ellipsoid

area.setEllipsoidalMode(True) #setting ellipsoidal mode

wb=iface.activeLayer()

feat = wb.selectedFeatures()

multiPart = feat[0].geometry().isMultipart()

if (multiPart is False):
    pol = feat[0].geometry().asPolygon()
    print "area is %.2f km2" % (area.measurePolygon(pol[0])/1e6)
else:
    pol = feat[0].geometry().asMultiPolygon()
    print "There are %d polygons" % len(pol)
    i=1
    for geom in pol:
        print "area%d is %.2f km2" % (i,area.measurePolygon(geom[0])/1e6)
        i +=1
```

Its implementation in Python Console for Alaska (I used another shapefile) results in:

[image]

Comment: any ideea on how to do this in MySQL 5.6 using spatial extensions  ?

Comment: You should call area.computeAreaInit() as mentioned in another answer before calling area.measurePolygon(), otherwise you will get the answer as 0.0

Answer (score 2):

---

**EDITING: CALL QgsDistanceArea().computeAreaInit()**

```
    wb=iface.activeLayer()
    feat = wb.selectedFeatures()
    area = QgsDistanceArea() #creating object
    area.setEllipsoid('WGS84')  #setting ellipsoid
    True
    area.setEllipsoidalMode(True) #setting ellipsoidal mode

    area.computeAreaInit() # CALL THIS BEFORE CALCULATING AREA !!!

    geom = feat[0].geometry().asPolygon()
    print "Continental Spain area is %.2f km2" % (area.measurePolygon(geom[0])/1e6)
```

Now I have result 494564854638.802 Square Meters (VERY GOOD). Before calculating area, call method of QgsDistanceArea class computeAreaInit().

Comment: Can you please explain, why you are calling the class computeAreaInit() before calculating the area! This would be interesting for those who want to benefit from your answer.

Comment: without computeAreaInit, result from [Answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137830/28647) for spain feature is 0.00 km2.