# Adding Area column in Polygon layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, geometry, qgis-processing, area, pyqgis-3

I have a `WardBoundary.shp` file with Polygon Features in it. I have to calculate the area of each Polygon and write into attribute Table.

I can do manually by using '$area` but I need to automate this process using Pyqgis3.

I have seen [Add area column using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168661) but I am unable to get area as well as code.

Comment: Does this answer provide any more insight?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/180748/43

Comment: I am checking it right now. by the way for the first one I am getting "QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'" error

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I put some lines that must be execute from the python console of Qgis. I use [the Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modify-features) of Qgis 3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorDataProvider
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

# ****Choose**** where you want to calculate your area

# from a layer stored somewhere in your computer
layer = QgsVectorLayer('c:\temp\ward_boundary.shp', 'WardBoundary', 'ogr')

# in the active layer in the TreeLayer (the undelying layer)
#layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Here we get the capabilities of your layer (Add attribute layer, edit feature ect ..
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

# We make a list of fields from their name
fields_name = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()]

# We check if we can add an attribute to the layer.
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    # We check if the attribute field is not exist
    if "Area" not in fields_name:
        # We add the field name Area and with the double type (it can be integer or text
        layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("Area", QVariant.Double)])
        # We update layer's field otherwise we'll not have the field
        layer.updateFields()
        # Recreate the list field by the name to have index of the field
        fields_name = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()]
        # we get the index of the Area field
        fareaidx = fields_name.index('Area')
    else:
        # We are here because there is a field name Area
        print("The Area field is already added")
        # Recreate the list field by the name to have index of the field
        fields_name = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()]
        # we get the index of the Area field
        fareaidx = fields_name.index('Area')

# Here we check if we can change attribute of the layer
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:
    # we loop^on every feature
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        # For each feature :
        # We calculate the area and put the index of the field Area
        # We round the area value by 2 digit
        attrs = {fareaidx : round(feature.geometry().area(), 2)}
        # We change the the value of Area Field for this feature.
        layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature.id() : attrs})
```

Comment: Hi thanks for brief explantion of code . I understood it .but even after making use of this code, I got Area column but with no value in it. Here is the link to my shp file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gJrGoXhRKCuTEn-kHf-AYqL7GCA7McJX

Comment: For me it works also with your data test. Did you put the right path to the layer ? Or are you executing this script from the active layer ?

Comment: Ohh yes it worked for me too now . sorry i missed double inverted column rather then single inverted column. in the path  Thank you so much :)