# Calculating polygon areas using Field Calculator in PyQGIS

Tags: field-calculator, geometry, pyqgis-3, area, qgsexpression

I am trying to calculate areas for polygons in QGIS 3.16.10 using PyQGIS 3 as you would with the Field Calculator. I am trying to use QgsExpression to create the necessary expression. However, the API documentation requires that the geomCalculator is set. What does this mean?

Comment: see the accepted answer here --> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323006/adding-area-column-in-polygon-layer-using-pyqgis

Comment: Thanks. I used the Cookbook geometry predicates example in the answer you provided

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html#geometry-predicates-and-operations