# Get just not null values from intersection of shapefile and buffer with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, intersection

I generated a buffer using this question: [Creating buffer circle x kilometers from point using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/creating-buffer-circle-x-kilometers-from-point-using-python)

I did an intersection with this buffer and a shapefile using:

```
intersection_origem = shp_geom.intersection(Polygon(buffer_origem))
```

The "intersection_origem" looks like above:
[image]

Apparently nothing wrong with it, but I need just the not null values like it's from 2595 to 2597. Is there a "filter" that can do what I need?

I tried the code above but with no success:

```
for i in range(0,intersection_origem.length):
    if (intersection_origem[i] != ""):
        print(intersection_origem[i])
```

Comment: `None` is the usual Python equivalent of `NULL` -- Empty string is a valid string with length zero. You should always debug the type of the data when in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(0,intersection_origem.length):
    if intersection_origem[i]:
        print(intersection_origem[i])
```

empty strings and `None` both evaluate to `false`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more info about what is truthy and falsey in Python.

By the way, it is not recommended to iterate through lists the way you are doing in Python. A more "pythonic" way of doing it would be like this:

```
for intersection in intersection_origem:
    if intersection:
        print(intersection)
```