# Polygon Produced Using Geopandas Buffer Not Correct Size

Tags: python, polygon, buffer, geopandas, polygon-creation

I have created 2 plots as pictured:

[image]

The blue (with red outline) polygon should be a 10KM circle around the central dark green point in both plots.

This is **correct for the right hand side plot** (the purple pin on the red line with a light green circle around it is at 10.02KM).

However this is **not the case for the left plot**. This polygon was created using Geopandas `buffer()`. Here the same purple pin at 10.02KM is far to the left of its expected location (again surrounded by a light green circle.) The red outline of this polygon is at ~6.2/6.3KM instead of 10KM as expected.

I need to perform a number of geospatial operations on this polygon data including estimating the population of this polygon, hence I need to use GeoPandas.

It appears that my current use of `buffer()` does not produce a 10,000 Metre buffer radius as expected, but rather one of ~6200-6300 Metres.

How can I make my Geopandas code produce the desired polygon, as illustrated on the right plot?

My code:

```
# CREATE DF WITH SINGLE ROW
df = pd.DataFrame([[51.502687, -3.538329, 2242, 1, 47, 10.00]],
                   columns = ["lat","long","num_of_trucks","performance","num_of_routes","avg_agent_dist_trav_km"]
                 )
```

```
# CONVERT ABOVE DF TO GEODF USING LONGITUDE AND LATITUDE:
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["long"],df["lat"]),
                                                                 crs={"init": "epsg:4326"})
```

```
# REPROJECT TO CRS THAT USES METRES SO CAN CALCULATE BUFFER RADIUS 
gdf.to_crs(epsg=3395,inplace=True)

# CALCULATE 10KM BUFFER RADIUS <<< THIS STEP SEEMS TO BE CAUSE OF MY ISSUE
gdf["geometry"] = gdf.geometry.buffer(10000)
gdf["current_buffer_radius_in_metres"] = 10000
```

```
# CHANGE THE CRS BACK TO ALLOW PLOTTING IN GEOVIEWS
gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326,inplace=True)
```

```
# PRODUCE POLYGON FOR LEFT PLOT. THIS IS THE INCORRECT POLYGON:
polyplot = gv.Polygons(gdf).opts(tools=["hover","tap"],line_color="red",line_width=3,fill_alpha=0.35)
```

```
# PRODUCE DF TO PRODUCE TRACKER POINT PINS PLOT.
trackersdf  = pd.DataFrame([[51.605475, -3.43845, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 13.370608, 8.30811],
                           [51.591792, -3.242236, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 22.806912, 14.171558],
                           [51.511891, -3.581327, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 3.156072, 1.961092],
                           [51.512954, -3.546054, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 1.261932, 0.784128],
                           [51.722711, -3.248196, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 31.672704, 19.680506],
                           [51.562025, -3.27612, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 19.355701, 12.027075],
                           [51.530072, -3.67591, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 10.024503, 6.228937],
                           [51.667927, -3.52239, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 18.417676, 11.444213],
                           [51.666187, -3.3038, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 24.395822, 15.158861],
                           [51.644319, -3.644031, "Portishead Depo Bridgend", 17.378509, 10.798505]],
                           columns = ["lat", "lon", "depo_name", "tracker_dist_trav_km", "tracker_dist_trav_miles"])
```

```
# PRODUCE TRACKER POINT PINS PLOT (USED FOR BOTH PLOTS):
tracker_pins = gv.Points(trackersdf,kdims = ["lon","lat"],
                                    vdims = ["tracker_dist_trav_km","tracker_dist_trav_miles"],
                              label = "Trackers").opts(tools=["hover","tap"],
                                                        color="purple",size = 8,
                                                        line_color="white",
                                                        hover_color="red",
                                                        hover_line_color="white",line_width=0.1,
                                                        legend_position="top")
```

```
# PRODUCE DEPO POINTS PIN PLOT (USED FOR BOTH PLOTS):
depo_pin = gv.Points(df, 
                     kdims = ["long","lat"],
                     vdims = ["num_of_trucks","performance","num_of_routes","avg_agent_dist_trav_km"]
                          ).opts(tools=["hover","tap"],
                                 color="green",size = 15,
                                 line_color="white",hover_color="orange",
                                 hover_line_color="white",line_width=2)
```

```
### PRODUCE POLYGON FOR THE RIGHT PLOT. THIS PRODUCES THE CORRECT POLYGON, HOWEVER I WISH TO REPRODUCE THIS USING GEOPANDAS.
### THIS IS ADAPTED FROM: 
### https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/creating-buffer-circle-x-kilometers-from-point-using-python

proj_wgs84 = pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')

def geodesic_point_buffer(index):
    lat = df.iloc[index]["lat"]
    lon = df.iloc[index]["long"]
    km = df.iloc[index]["avg_agent_dist_trav_km"]
    # Azimuthal equidistant projection
    aeqd_proj = '+proj=aeqd +lat_0={lat} +lon_0={lon} +x_0=0 +y_0=0'
    project = partial(
        pyproj.transform,
        pyproj.Proj(aeqd_proj.format(lat=lat, lon=lon)),
        proj_wgs84)
    buf = Point(0, 0).buffer(km * 1000)  # DISTANCE IN METRES
    # THIS WILL RETURN THE SET OF POINTS (LONG&LAT) THAT TOGETHER MAKE UP THE RADIUS AROUND EACH DEPO
    # RETURNED TUPLE 1. DATA:
    tracker_radius_coords = transform(project, buf).exterior.coords[:]
    # RETURNED TUPLE 2. PLOT:
    radius = gv.Points(tracker_radius_coords).opts(color="red",size=5)
    # RETURNED TUPLE 3. PLOT:
    radius_poly = gv.Polygons(tracker_radius_coords).opts(tools=["hover","tap"],line_color="red",line_width=3,fill_alpha=0.35)
     
    # RETURN MULTIPLE COMPONENTS SO THAT I CAN USE THEM ELSEWHERE
    return tracker_radius_coords, radius, radius_poly
```

```
# PRODUCE THE RIGHT POLYGON BY CALLING THE ABOVE FUNCTION:
radius_poly = geodesic_point_buffer(0)[2]
```

```
# PRODUCE LEFT PLOT. NB THIS IS WRONG.
plot = tracker_pins * depo_pin * polyplot * gvts.OSM
plot.opts(width=800,height=900)
```

```
# PRODUCE RIGHT PLOT. NB THIS IS RIGHT, BUT DOES NOT USE GEOPANDAS AS REQUIRED.
plot2 = tracker_pins * depo_pin * radius_poly * gvts.OSM
plot2.opts(width=800,height=900)
```

```
# USE A PYVIZ PANEL TO SHOW LEFT AND RIGHT PLOT SIDE BY SIDE AS PER ABOVE PICTURE:
publish = pn.Column(
                pn.Row("## Geopandas Version, 10000 metre Buffer Radius used. INCORRECT POLYGON PRODUCED", plot,
                       "## Non Geopandas Version, 10km Polygon produced. CORRECT POLYGON PRODUCED", plot2))

publish.show(port = 10075,open=True)
```

Comment: don't use mercator projection for analysis it is off by a factor cos(lat)

Answer (score 1):

Switching to using EPSG:27700 fixed my issue.