# Generate a circle of coordinates around a point, but I'm getting an Oval

Tags: python, haversine

I'm using the following code to attempt to generate a circle of coordinates a fixed distance (in this case 1km) around a point. I'm basing the formula on [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), but the output I'm seeing in Google Earth is an Oval, and not a Circle.

```
import simplekml
import math

kml = simplekml.Kml()

def GetCirclePointCoordinate(point, bearing):
    
    lat = point[0]
    lon = point[1]
    d = point[2]

    R = 6371
    brng = bearing * (math.pi / 180)
    lat1 = lat * (math.pi / 180)
    lon1 = lon * (math.pi / 180)

    lat2 = (math.asin(math.sin(lat1)*math.cos(d/R) + math.cos(lat1)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(brng)))*(180/math.pi)
    lon2 = (lon1 + math.atan2(math.sin(brng)*math.sin(d/R)*math.cos(lat1),math.cos(d/R)-math.sin(lat1)*math.sin(lat2)))*(180/math.pi)

    return lon2,lat2

point = (51.5014,-0.1419,1) # Buckingham Palace, London

circle_coords = []
for deg in range(360):
    circle_coords.append(GetCirclePointCoordinate(point,deg))

ls = kml.newlinestring(name="radius", description="radius")
ls.coords=circle_coords
kml.save("circle.kml")
```

The output I'm seeing is depicted below:

[image: Oval around Buckingham Palace]

I was looking at a solution in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289044/creating-buffer-circle-x-kilometers-from-point-using-python) but wondered if there was a way to do this using a more native solution without the various library imports.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please do **not** ever use EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) to carry out any sort of distance related analysis. The longitude (X) axis is distorted to infinity as you move north or south of the Equator.

Comment: To compliment Ian's comment, your dataset needs to be in metres or feet. So reprojected your data.

Comment: @IanTurton the calculation isnt being done in EPSG:3857 though - its in lat-long using Haversine distance. Which should return lat-long points of a circle of 1km around the centre. Which should look like a circle in this projection - otherwise the fountain in the centre would look oval too, wouldn't it? I'd see what you get for a point on the equator, and make sure the formula is correctly coded - test some points of well-known separation in lat and in long.

Comment: but Google Maps is using EPSG:3857

Comment: A circle almost never looks like a circle in most projections. Web Mercator is an awful projection for the UK because the high latitude distorts significantly. The images used in Maps are processed so they don't look awful, so your basis of comparison is faulty.

Comment: Interesting, I'm a complete n00b to this so I'm learning from your comments which are appreciated. So I plotted the same at the equator and the output in Google Earth does indeed appear circular and not oval. So, am I right in thinking my code works, its just the way it's displayed in the Mercator view that is causing the oval?

Comment: Also, when using [this](https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/circleplot) online service, it generates a perfect circle each time. I don't know the back-end logic of course, but the output of this tool is essentially what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: The KML that the onsite site creates shows the coordinates at 1 degree steps with comments `<!-- 358.000 degrees @ 6.213712 km --> 27.993705,60.089889,0`. Compare them with the values that you get with your code. Because the client that you use it Google Earth the 10 km circle should not appear oval. It seems that there is something wrong in your code. Comments about web Mercator and Google maps are valid but do not apply to GE.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 I took that advice and did see a lot of discrepancy between my output and theirs. In this end I took to using the formula in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877524/calculating-coordinates-given-a-bearing-and-a-distance) which gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the points of a circle in decimal degrees from a center point and radius in meters, you can use shapely and pyproj for the reprojection, and export the circle to KML using simplekml.

The azimuthal equidistant projection (aka aeqd) is an azimuthal map projection that provides points on the map that are at proportionally correct distances from the center point. Create circle in aeqd coordinate space then reproject to WGS-84.

```python
from shapely.geometry import Point
from pyproj import Transformer
from shapely.ops import transform
import simplekml

# Buckingham Palace, London
lat = 51.5014
lng = -0.1419
radius = 1000   # radius in meters

local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(
    lat, lng
)
wgs84_to_aeqd = Transformer.from_proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs',
                                      local_azimuthal_projection)
aeqd_to_wgs84 = Transformer.from_proj(local_azimuthal_projection,
                                      '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
# Get polygon with lat lon coordinates
point_transformed = Point(wgs84_to_aeqd.transform(lng, lat))

buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius)
circle = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84.transform, buffer)

# Next export as KML

kml = simplekml.Kml()
ls = kml.newlinestring(tessellate=1,
                       coords=list(circle.exterior.coords),
                       altitudemode=simplekml.AltitudeMode.clamptoground)
ls.style.linestyle.color = 'ffff00aa'  # purple
ls.style.linestyle.width = 3
kml.save("circle.kml")
```

**Output:**

[image: View of circle in Google Earth]

Comment: nice solution - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another direct geometrical approach, **without having to play with projections** is to rely on libraries intended to do geodesics computation.

The [geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) is the go to solution for this. It has bindings in many languages.

[Python binding](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/)

The geodesic Direct and Inverse problem descriptions here:
https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/geodesics.html#solution-of-geodesic-problems

Quoting:

> Traditionally two geodesic problems are considered:
>
> the direct problem — given φ1, λ1, α1, s12, determine φ2, λ2, and α2; this is solved by Geodesic.Direct.
>
> the inverse problem — given φ1, λ1, φ2, λ2, determine s12, α1, and α2; this is solved by Geodesic.Inverse.

(`φ_i`, `λ_i`, are spherical angles, `s_ij` segments length, `α_i` are azimuth)

A good example is this python library to plot circles:
https://polycircles.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Implementation details:

- determine nb of circle vertices N for the circle
- convert that into N bearings (from 0 to 360°)
- for loop: compute N place/bearing/distance point from center (known as the geodesic Direct problem (`geodesic.Geodesic.WGS84.Direct`)
- voilà: you've got your N points that are truely equidistant from center
- now, put that in a line or polygon in your favorite plotting tool (eg: LineString in google earth)

see the code source from:
https://github.com/adamatan/polycircles/blob/main/polycircles/polycircles.py

quoting:

```py
class Polycircle(Shape):
    """A polygonial approximation of a circle in WGS84 coordinates.
    >>> import polycircles
    >>> number_of_vertices = 20
    >>> polycircle = polycircles.Polycircle(latitude=31.611878, longitude=34.505351, radius=100, number_of_vertices=number_of_vertices)
    >>> len(polycircle.to_lat_lon()) == number_of_vertices + 1
    True
    """

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude, radius, number_of_vertices=DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES):
        """
        Arguments:
        latitude -- WGS84 latitude, between -90.0 and 90.0.
        longitude -- WGS84 longitude, between -180.0 and 180.0.
        radius -- Circle radius in meters.
        number_of_vertices -- Number of vertices for the approximation
        polygon.
        """
        # Value assertions
        assert number_of_vertices >= 3, "The minimal number of vertices in a polygon is 3."
        assert radius > 0, "Radius can only have positive values."
        assert -180 <= longitude <= 180, "Longitude must be between -180 and 180 degrees."
        assert -90 <= latitude <= 90, "Latitude must be between -90 and 90 degrees."

        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.radius = radius
        self.number_of_vertices = number_of_vertices

        vertices = []
        for i in range(number_of_vertices):
            degree = 360.0/number_of_vertices*i
            vertex = geodesic.Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(latitude, longitude, degree, radius)
            lat = vertex['lat2']
            lon = vertex['lon2']
            vertices.append((lat, lon)) # because it is intended for KML, longitudes come first
        vertices.append(vertices[0])
        self.vertices = tuple(vertices) # tuplification of coords (e.g. for simplekml)
```

usage here:

https://polycircles.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kmls.html

quoting the usage example:

```
from polycircles import polycircles

polycircle = polycircles.Polycircle(latitude=40.768085,
                                    longitude=-73.981885,
                                    radius=200,
                                    number_of_vertices=36)
kml = simplekml.Kml()
pol = kml.newpolygon(name="Columbus Circle, Manhattan",
                                         outerboundaryis=polycircle.to_kml())
pol.style.polystyle.color = \
        simplekml.Color.changealphaint(200, simplekml.Color.green)
kml.save("test_kml_polygon_3_manhattan.kml")
```

NB: polycircles has a small limitation in google earth near poles and date change meridian, this is discussed here https://github.com/adamatan/polycircles/issues/2 with a partial fix proposal (not included in polycircle yet ...)

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are talking about using another library.  That's great most of the time because you don't have to re-invent the wheel.  However, it doesn't answer it from the perspective that you can't import anything.  My answer addresses that concern.

To get an accurate circle plot over the curvature of the earth, you need to solve for the geodesic direct problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae

You have to project a circle over an ellipsoid surface by calculating the distance of the straight line over the curve at each degree/radian point.
Other approaches are naïve and will warp as you go over larger areas.  You will have to parse out the above maths and appropriately implement it in whatever language you are in.  Here's an excellent example in C#:

https://gist.github.com/jhmt/f57c44139cf09a532c7efa60c6158913

You can reverse engineer these calculations into any language relatively easily from this example.  For people who need to generate a kml like file and to programmatically generate the circle radius without using a library that has tons of baggage, this is going to be your best bet.

Otherwise, of course, I would highly suggest using a framework like ARCGis or libraries and modules as stated above because they will greatly help you with what you need to get done in a short period of time without having to spend the time re-implementing these complex functions.