# How to buffer a pair of longitude and latitude coordinates in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, buffer, latitude-longitude, sf

I have a pair of longitude and latitude coordinates, and I want to plot a 500 meter buffer around it using `leaflet` or `mapview`. `st_buffer`, however, does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data.

Initial code:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(lon = -121.9552, lat = 37.35411)
coordinates(df) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df)
#....
# Something goes here, but I don't know what?
#...
st_buffer(df_sf, 500)

Warning message:
In st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs) :
st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data
```

What's the missing piece?

Comment: Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/121539 to dynamically project each point using aeqd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use st\_buffer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311502/how-to-use-st-buffer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your point should be in a Projected Coordinate System. If it is in a geographic coordinate system, the values will be in decimal degrees.

I am not sure what you use over there, but I have picked NAD83 California Albers, which uses metres as its unit.

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

df <- data.frame(lon = -121.9552, lat = 37.35411)
coordinates(df) <- c("lon", "lat")
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df) %>% st_transform(3488) #transform to NAD83(NSRS2007) / California Albers
df_sf_buff <- st_buffer(df_sf, 500)
plot(df_sf_buff)
```

Comment: If you want to avoid all the faff of building a point using sp::coordinates, you can do it purely in `sf` with: `df = st_sfc(st_point(cbind(-121, 37)),crs=4326)` - then you don't need `rgdal` or `rgeos`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make `st_buffer` to output **correct** results, make sure:

- the CRS unit is the same as the one used in the `dist` argument from `st_buffer`.

AND,

- the CRS is in a projected coordinate system (i.e., with planar coordinates), as stated in [wl1234's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303126/how-do-i-buffer-a-pair-of-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-in-r/303136#303136). This is because the geometrical operations from `sf` (and `rgeos`) package come from the GEOS library, which assume coordinates to be planar. This is why you get the message `st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data` (even if you were using degrees in the `dist` argument).

Comment: Good additional information.