# How to use st_buffer?

Tags: r, sf, plot, st

I would like to calculate a buffer of 5km around country polygons. However, I somehow always get a warning and an error. Here is a reproducible example code.

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(tmap) 
library(rnaturalearth)
countries_sp <- ne_countries(scale = 10)

countries_sp <- countries_sp[(countries_sp@data$geounit %in% "France"), ]

proj4string(countries_sp) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") 

countries_for_buff <- st_as_sf(countries_sp, crs ="+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")

countries_buff_5km <- st_buffer( countries_for_buff, 5000)
```

here the warning:

```
dist is assumed to be in decimal degrees (arc_degrees).
Warning message:
In st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs, endCapStyle = endCapStyle,  :
st_buffer does not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data
```

Then

```
tm_shape(countries_sp) +
  tm_polygons() +
tm_shape(countries_buff_5km) +
  tm_polygons()
```

gives the error

```
 Error in if (all(tiny) && show.messages) warning("all relative area sizes are below thres.poly",  : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What am I doing wrong? I guess there is something about the projection that does not quite work out the way it should.

Comment: Which query language?

Comment: The language is R, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is unnecessary because the object is already in that coordinate system:

```
proj4string(countries_sp) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

This doesn't do a coordinate transformation - the `crs` argument is ignored - what made you think it did something?

```
countries_for_buff <- st_as_sf(countries_sp, crs ="+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

If you don't believe its ignored, try:

```
> countries_for_buff <- st_as_sf(countries_sp, crs ="bogus")
>
```

So then when you do:

```
countries_buff_5km <- st_buffer( countries_for_buff, 5000)
```

then `countries_for_buff` is *still* in lat-long coordinates.

To convert from one to another you need either `spTransform` for sp objects or `st_transform` for `sf` objects.

so something like this on the `sp` object:

```
  csp2 = spTransform(countries_sp,"+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

Comment: great thank you! Because the plotting `st_buffer` does not accept `sp` objects, I used `st_as_sf`
 and the warning let me believe that something about the projection was wrong so I just simply tried some other projections

Comment: If you want to buffer `sp` objects then use `gBuffer` from the `rgeos` package. But `sf` objects are mostly better and I'd advise converting to `sf` as early as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I'm dealing with the same issue here.

The 'problem' is originated because the library comes from the GEOS library, which considers that coordinates in a two-dimensional, flat, Euclidian space. 
BUT....For longitude latitude data, this is not the case. For more info on this, please check... https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf6.html#what_is_this_epsg_code_all_about.

My work around....

1- Find your UTM. Use this function to find your UTM...

```
lonlat2UTM = function(lonlat) {
    utm = (floor((lonlat[1] + 180) / 6) %% 60) + 1
    if(lonlat[2] > 0) {
        utm + 32600
    } else{
        utm + 32700
        }
    }
```

Pass a latlong example of your data.... In my case..

```
coords_example = c(11.82166,59.12661)
EPSG_2_UTM <- lonlat2UTM(coords_example)
# To see the UTM
st_crs(EPSG_2_UTM)$proj4string
```

2- Re-project your data

```
LAYER_proj = st_transform(st_as_sf(ORIGINAL_LAYER_CRS), EPSG_2_UTM)
```

3- Run the buffer. Now in my case is in meters

```
buf_proj <- st_buffer(LAYER_proj, dist = 1500)
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.  If the questions are asking the same thing, then flag them as duplicates.  See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).